# Need advice on usage of 'for' vs 'of'

Tags: prepositions

What would be more correct to use:

"The graph **of** boys indicates ..."

or

"The graph **for** boys indicates ..."?

To me they both sound fine, but I would opt for *for*, because *of* seems possessive here while I intend to refer to the graph in which the data of a group of boys are displayed. The previous sentence also contains *of* in similar context of my question, but here *of* seems better than *for*.

Comment: "Of" would refer to what the graph contains; "for" would refer to how the graph is used. If it contains data about boys, the it is the graph *of* boys. If it contains data which boys will read and use, then it is the graph *for* boys.

Comment: Both are correct. I'd use *graph for* by default and *graph of* only where *for* would present problems.

Comment: @ScottM Not so in math, though.

Comment: "because *of* seems possessive" -- The preposition *of* and the "possessive" are not that simple and straight-forward.

Comment: Clearly it is not as straightforward as I had hoped. I will go for `for`, as suggested by @Kris. This feels right to me

Answer (score 0):

I would use neither. "The 'boys' graph" seems more on point to me. If the word "graph" needs to take precedence, "The graph regarding boys" might do, though that feels overwrought.

Comment: To me the boys' graph sounds as though the boys made a graph that is now 'theirs' (i.e. possessive)

Comment: Please note the quote at the front of the word boys.